# how to display listview while typing on edittext without using filter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

i have created an application in which it has to display list view when the user types on the edit text. Thing is shouldn't use filter. can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Why don't you want to have the filter?

Comment: do you want to show suggestions...?

Comment: for example if i enter the postal code it has to display all the address or area which comes under that particular postal code in list view.

Comment: use edittext addtextchange listener or key event on edit text...and check by edittext.getText().toString to the string you want like "postalcode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//imports

public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
  private EditText searchField;
  private SearchActivity activity;
  private ListView listView;

  protect void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances){
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    activity = this;

    searchField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchField);
    searchField.addTextChangedListener(this);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(Adapter<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3){
        //action when an item is clicked
      }
    });
  }  

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(final Editable searchField){
    listView.setAdapter(null); //refresh list items

    if(searchField.length()>0){
      //do your searches here
      listView.setAdapter(new YourCustomAdapter());
    }
  }     

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

}
```